# dojo datagrid query date range

Tags: datagrid, dojo, filtering

I am using **Enhancedgrid** with an **ItemFileWriteStore** to fetch a list of items, each one having a name, a description and a date formatted like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

I want to be able to filter **client-side** (server request is not an option) on a date range and hide all elements that don't belongs to the selected range.

I already have a filter on the name, and the way I am filtering it's the following code `myGrid.filter({"colname": "the text searched"});`

Is it possible (I haven't found any example on the internet) to filter between a date range with the same `.filter()` method ?

I have, so far, tried some of the followings, without success:

```
// none of this works
myGrid.filter({'dateCol': {largerThanOrEqualTo: '2015-01-01'}})
myGrid.filter({'dateCol': '>=2015-01-01'})
myGrid.filter({'dateCol': ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01']})
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture, or more clear description of what you are trying to implement? The code you provided is unclear and doesn't explain your problem at all

Comment: excuse my messy description, was too clear in my head, I have updated the question.